# Android SeekBar Doesn't Move Smoothly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, imagebutton, seekbar

I'm trying to write a `Camera` app in android. I wanted to use a `SeekBar` for zoom in/zoom out of the camera. Here goes my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <SeekBar android:id="@+id/sliderZoom"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#000000">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/flash"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:onClick="onFlashClick" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/zoom"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:onClick="onZoomClick" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

If I remove either of the `ImageButton`, my `SeekBar` moves smoothly. But it doesn't move smoothly if I've both of the `ImageButton`. I tried to run the app both in `portrait` and `landscape` mode. The problem remains same in both mode.

How can I solve it?

EDIT: As per some comment, I feel to add some more information. Right now there is no event handler for the `SeekBar`. It doesn't zoom in or zoom out the camera. It is just one simple `SeekBar`' with maximum value set to some random integer. For my case I tried 5 to 500. In every case I've the problem. By smooth move I mean when I try to slide it with touch it should move easily, should not halt. If there is one `ImageButton`, I can slide the `SeekBar` pointer left/right without any problem. But if there are two `ImageButton`, the pointer doesn't move that easily. It looks like each time the the pointer is moved by one unit, some time consuming operation runs on the UI thread which halts the UI from capturing touch event. Though the fact is there is no time consuming operation in UI thread. There is not a single function written for any type of computation. I didn't even add the camera preview in the `FrameLayout` or camera isn't initialized

More Edit: I just found out one interesting turn of event. If the image source is same image(doesn't matter which one) for both `ImageButton`, then it works perfectly. But if I've two different image for two `ImageButton`, then it starts causing the problem. I hope this new information will help to get some idea of what is happening. The resolution of the images are 1299x1299 and less than 40kb in size.

Comment: What do you mean by 'move smooth'? Also when do you expect smooth movement? When it is moved by touch or when you set the zoom level manually? Also you should provide your java code.

Comment: I edited my question with some more details as per your question.

Comment: I tried the layout you specified with two images of the correct size and could not replicate the issue. Seems as if it is in your code.

Comment: by the way, your drawables are 26mb when they are loaded into memory. It is 1299 * 1299 * 4  (rgba-channels) * 4 (32 bit-color) bytes per image. You should scale them down. see https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: that solved the problem. I had to scale down the image files. Thanks @leoderprofi

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not a problem. Camera zoom level is not so much. Basically zoom level is 5-7. So, as you have used SeekBar as your zoom controller it means your seekbar's max level is 7(suppoose). For this reason, it buffer per level when you pull the bar. 
For your test, you can set value **seekBar.setMax(30)** and then pull your seekbar. I hope you will get that smooth

Comment: You are ignoring the fact that I said it moves smoothly if I remove one of the ImageButton. So it is not due to zoom level being 5-7 as for the same zoom level it moves smoothly when there is only one button. Also to make me sure, I set maximum value 500 for SeekBar. Still it has the same issue.